# How can I convert xs:dayTimeDuration to milliseconds in XPath 2.0?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a value of the type xs:dayTimeDuration and I want to know how many milliseconds are in this duration.

Example: 3 minutes and 5 seconds in xs:dayTimeDuration is `PT3M5S` and it is 185000 milliseconds.

How can I convert xs:dayTimeDuration to milliseconds in XPath 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`xs:dayTimeDuration('PT3M5S') div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0.001S')`